# How to use that github api right?

Tags: python, github, pip

How can I install this package?

I installed and updated pip,setuptools,git but I couldn't install:

C:\Users\shait>pip install git+https://github.com/SocksPls/hltv-api.git

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/SocksPls/hltv-api.git
  Cloning https://github.com/SocksPls/hltv-api.git to c:\users\shait\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-h5h_opsb
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/SocksPls/hltv-api.git 'C:\Users\shait\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-h5h_opsb'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\shait\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\shait\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-h5h_opsb\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\shait\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-h5h_opsb\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\shait\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-h5h_opsb\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\shait\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-h5h_opsb\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\shait\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\shait\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-h5h_opsb\\setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating setup.py for installing API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687004/creating-setup-py-for-installing-api)

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\shait\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-h5h_opsb\setup.py'
```

is telling you pip can't find a `setup.py` file.  If you look at the repository on Github, you can see there is no `setup.py`, nor any other packaging-related files, so the software is not installable using pip.  You need to manually download it to a suitable directory and install the requirements.