# creating setup.py for installing API

Tags: python, github, pip

https://github.com/SocksPls/hltv-api.git this one when i tried to install i get a this error

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/SocksPls/hltv-api.git
  Cloning https://github.com/SocksPls/hltv-api.git to c:\users\shait\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-h5h_opsb
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/SocksPls/hltv-api.git 'C:\Users\shait\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-h5h_opsb'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\shait\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\shait\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-h5h_opsb\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\shait\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-h5h_opsb\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\shait\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-h5h_opsb\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\shait\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-h5h_opsb\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\shait\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\shait\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-h5h_opsb\\setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output
```

Pip can't download without setup.py file, how can i create it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use that github api right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58679973/how-to-use-that-github-api-right)

Comment: Please don't post your quesstion multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project you linked does not have a `setup.py`, so `pip` cannot actually install it. What you are looking for is most likely to do:

```
git clone https://github.com/SocksPls/hltv-api
```

Go into the new `/hltv-api` folder and do:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

From there you will be able to use/modify/import the `main.py` inside this project. Note, however, that you will only be able to import the `main.py` file from inside the same directory. Create a `tool.py` within the same dir and use the module:

```py
import main as hltv
hltv.top5teams()
```